# FOSRestBundle serializer results in too much queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder, fosrestbundle

I use FOSrestbundle in my API to get my objects as a JSON.
So my controller look like that:

```
public function getArticleAction($id)
    {
        $article = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ApiBundle:Article')
            ->find($id);
        return $this->handleView($this->view($article));
    }
```

And my issue is that an article contains comments, added by users so my json looks like that:

```
{
    "title": "My Article",
    "comments": [
        {
            "content": "my first comment",
            "added_by": {
                "username": "John"
            }
        },
        {
            "content": "my second comment",
            "added_by": {
                "username": "Smith"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I render it, there is too many queries, for each comment there is a query to get user informations.

Do I have to get my article object with a querybuilder and lot of join (because it is just an example but I have a lot more relations) to get all the informations in one query or is there an other trick to avoid it ?

Comment: i don't have deep knowledge regarding restful apis with sf2 but i think you should google about exclusion policy with jmsserailser to only include necessary things from your graph.http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/#get-what

Answer (score 0):

You should use [EAGER](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) loading for `added_by` relation while querying your data using `Doctrine`. This way you will query all data you need for serialization at once.